# How to add values to nested array in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, arrays, mongodb, nested, frontend

I have customers data with nested arrays. I have axios.get and axios.post. i would like to display the data and also add values to the nested array amount. I have data that looks like this:
JSON Data

```
    customers:[
        {
          "_id": "6389d19a3b28b9e4af3694f8",
          "fullName": "WADE IVAN",
          "clientdetails": {
            "_id": "6389d1193b28b9e4af3694f2",
            "dateofBirth": "1990-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "age": 32,
            "__v": 0
          },
          "Paymentdetails":{
            "paymentReferenceCode": "1",
            "paymentType": "Cash",
            "paymentDescription": "ACCOMODATION",
            "amount": "100",
            "paymentDiscount": 20,
            "totals": 100,
            "date": "Jan 20, 2022",
            "__v": 0
        }
       }
      ]
```

What am trying to do is to add values to the array customers.paymentdetails.amount

customers.paymentdetails.Amount = '500'

to have JSON data like this

```
customers:[
        {
          "_id": "6389d19a3b28b9e4af3694f8",
          "fullName": "WADE IVAN",
          "clientdetails": {
            "_id": "6389d1193b28b9e4af3694f2",
            "dateofBirth": "1990-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "age": 32,
            "__v": 0
          },
          "Paymentdetails":{
            "paymentReferenceCode": "1",
            "paymentType": "Cash",
            "paymentDescription": "ACCOMODATION",
            "amount": "100","500",  
            "paymentDiscount": 20,
            "totals": 100,
            "date": "Jan 20, 2022",
            "__v": 0
        }
       }
      ]
```

addAmount.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import axios from "axios";
import $ from "jquery";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      customers: [
        {
          paymentdetails: {
            amount: "",
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleAddAmount = this.handleAddAmount.bind(this);
    this.handleAddPayment = this.handleAddPayment.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleAddAmount = (event) => {
    let amountArray = [...this.state.customers.paymentdetails.amount];
    const value = event.target.value;
    const index = amountArray.findIndex((amount) => amount === value);
    if (index > -1) {
      amountArray = [
        ...amountArray.slice(0, index),
        ...amountArray.slice(index + 1),
      ];
    } else {
      amountArray.push(value);
    }

    let newCustomer = this.state.paymentdetailsTable;
    newCustomer.find((x) => x === this.state.customers).paymentdetails.amount =
      amountArray;

    this.setState({ paymentdetails: newCustomer });
  };

  handleAddPayment = (customers) => {
    this.setState({ paymentdetails: customers });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBillingData();
  }
  getBillingData() {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:4000/customers`)
      .then((res) => {
        const customers = res.data;
        this.setState({
          customers,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const save = {
      paymentdetails: this.state.paymentdetails,
    };

    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:4000/customers/addpostamount`, save, {})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        return $(".alert-success").show();
      });
    this.setState({
      paymentdetails: "",
    });
  }

  render() {
    const customers = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="form-div">
            <h1>Add Payment Amount</h1>
            <Box
              component="form"
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              noValidate
              sx={{ mt: 1 }}
            >
              <div class="container, width:100%">
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        {customers.paymentdetails.map((item) => {
                          return (
                            <p>
                              <div>
                                <h7>
                                  <strong>paymentdetails</strong>
                                </h7>
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th className="thead">Date </th>
                                    <th className="thead">RefCode </th>
                                    <th className="thead">Type</th>
                                    <th className="thead">Description </th>
                                    <th className="thead">Amount </th>
                                    <th className="thead">Discount </th>
                                    <th className="thead">Total </th>
                                  </tr>

                                  <tr key={item.paymentdetails}>
                                    <td>{item.date}</td>
                                    <td>{item.paymentReferenceCode}</td>
                                    <td>{item.paymentType}</td>
                                    <td>{item.paymentDescription}</td>
                                    <td>{item.amount}</td>
                                    <td>{item.paymentDiscount}</td>
                                    <td>
                                      {item.totals}

                                      <Button
                                        variant="success"
                                        onClick={() =>
                                          this.handleAddPayment(item)
                                        }
                                      ></Button>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                      <span>
                                        <select
                                          onChange={this.handleAddAmount}
                                          value={this.amount}
                                        >
                                          <option value="Amount"></option>
                                          <option value="500">500</option>
                                          <option value="100">100</option>
                                          <option value="200">200</option>
                                          <option value="50">50</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </span>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                            </p>
                          );
                        })}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <Button type="submit" fullWidth sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}>
                <span className="btn btn-warning btn-block form-control form-group">
                  Submit
                </span>
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Am not able to display the data in the console am getting TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').

I would like to be able to display the nested array data and also be able to add the amount when i submit.

Comment: Please remove the excessive leading indentation from your code block (see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)). As long as you follow the guidance in ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541), then [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using optional chaining like:

```
customers?.paymentdetails?.map()
```

Or you can also do this instead:

```
customers && customers.paymentdetails.length && customer.paymentdetails.map( )
```

Comment: Thanks @Harry ve corrected the code and am able to display the nested array. But still am not able to post a new value to the array amount